# Visually wrong representation of very composite character

Tags: accents

I have chosen the notation

```
\hat{\widetilde{S_{\hat{n}}}}^{(1)}
```

to represent the Spin operator along axis `n` on particle `1` of a multi-partite system (physics).

I have copy & pasted that code. Whereas in the first instance it looks fine, there's a mistake (second non-subscript `n`) creeping in in the second. I suspect it's because of the `\left(` nearby.

The first instance is:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{SingleSpinMeasCompState}
\hat{S}_{\hat{n}} \rightarrow \hat{\widetilde{S_{\hat{n}}}}^{(1)} 
    = \hat{S}_{\hat{n}}^{(1)} \otimes \hat{\mathbb{I}}^{(2)}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

(works fine)

The second (bad) one is:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{SingletMeasProbabilities}
P \left( \hat{\widetilde{S_{\hat{n}}}}^{(1)} 
  \equalhat \pm \frac{\hbar}{2} \right) 
  = \bra{s} \left( \ket{\pm}_{\hat{n}} \bra{\pm}_{\hat{n}} \right) \ket{s} 
  = \mid \braket{s \mid \pm} \mid^2 
  = \frac{1}{2}.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

I forgot to provide the packages I used, which are:

```
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
```

The definition of `\equalhat` is:

```
\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\stackon[1.5pt]{=}{\stretchto{%
    \scalerel*[\widthof{=}]{\wedge}{\rule{1ex}{3ex}}}{0.5ex}}}}
```

Comment: you can use three backticks (or indent by 4 spaces, or use the `{}` button) for code blocks, but also it really helps if you make the examples complete documents so people can run them and see the issue, and test answers

Comment: If I try to make an example from your fragment I get an error `! Undefined control sequence. ` for `\equalhat` so I can not reproduce your issue.

Comment: Please tell us which symbol-related packages you load. `amssymb`? `physics`? `braket`? Something else?

Comment: Off-topic: `\mid \braket{s \mid \pm} \mid^2` is just wrong. It should likely be `\lvert \braket{s \vert \pm} \rvert^2`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the packages I used and more importantly: The definition for equalhat, sorry for that

Comment: @Mico Thank you for pointing that out.!

Comment: adding them as disconnected fragments still makes it harder fro people to help. See the code in Mico's answer it is a complete document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments and observations:

- In view of the fact that that one of the three `\hat{n}` terms in the first equations is noticeably (and unjustifiably too, right?) larger than the other two, I wouldn't claim that the first equation "works fine".
- Combining `\widetilde` with `\hat` can be very tricky, as your screenshots amply demonstrate. Anyway, I would *not* use `\widetilde` here, and I would replace all instances of `\hat{\widetilde{S_{\hat{n}}}}` with `\hat{\tilde{S}}_{\hat{n}}`.
- You haven't explained how `\equalhat` might be defined. Is

  ```
  \newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\widehat{=}}}
  ```

  acceptable?
- The expression

  ```
  \mid \braket{s \mid \pm} \mid^2
  ```

  is simply wrong. Do please write it as

  ```
  \lvert \braket{s \vert \pm} \rvert^2
  ```
- Following the template given in the user guide of the `mathtools` package, I've provided a three-argument version of the `\braket` command. This has forced me to replace your existing `\braket` command (see the preceding bullet point) with `\innerp`, a macro that's defined below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
% Define the following macros: \abs, \bra, \ket, and \braket
% (See the user guide of the 'mathtools' package for the
%  definition of the 3-argument '\braket' macro)
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs\lvert\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\bra\langle\rvert
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\ket\lvert\rangle
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\innerp\langle\rangle
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\braket[3]{\langle}{\rangle}%
   {#1\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#2\,\delimsize\vert\,\mathopen{}#3}
% Define \equalhat -- Did I guess correctly??
\newcommand\equalhat{\mathrel{\widehat{=}}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{SingleSpinMeasCompState}
\hat{S}_{\hat{n}} \rightarrow \hat{\tilde{S}}_{\hat{n}}^{(1)} 
= \hat{S}_{\hat{n}}^{(1)} \otimes \hat{\mathbb{I}}^{(2)}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{SingletMeasProbabilities}
\Pr \Bigl( \hat{\tilde{S}}_{\hat{n}}^{(1)} \equalhat \pm\frac{\hbar}{2} \Bigr) 
= \braket[\big]{s}{(\ket{\pm}_{\hat{n}}\bra{\pm}_{\hat{n}})}{s} 
= \abs[\big]{ \innerp{s\vert\pm} }^2 
= \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just around the time I posted this answer, the OP provided additional information about how `\equalhat` is defined and which packages are loaded. I think my suggestions about how to write `\hat{\tilde{S}}` and about not using the `\mid` macro improperly remain valid. However, the definitions of `\bra`, `\ket`, and `\braket` provided in my code may not be all that useful since they probably collide with the definitions given in the `braket` package.

Comment: I replaced \mid by \lvert, \mert, \right in the relevant places in my document.
I had first tried \hat{\tilde{S}}, but rejected it because the tilde is barely noticeable in some places, but the current issue with widetilde is clearly worse

Comment: it really depends on what is done the line after. Now all instances of that character - even with widetilde - seem to work fine